# --nice with cp for giving more processor priority on cp?

Tags: linux

How can I use --nice=-10 with cp command in linux ?

Following are the example when I tried the option and it gives the error unrecognized option
EX- error:

```
cp --nice=-20 -r dir1 /d/
cp: unrecognized option `--nice=-20'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nice` is a command on its own, it isn't an option to the `cp` command.

From `man nice`:

```
NAME
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

SYNOPSIS
       nice [OPTION] [COMMAND [ARG]...]

DESCRIPTION
       Run COMMAND with an adjusted niceness, which affects process scheduling.
       With no COMMAND, print the current niceness.  Nicenesses range from -20
       (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).

       -n, --adjustment=N
              add integer N to the niceness (default 10)
```

So for your purposes, you would use this:

```
nice -n -20 cp -r dir1 /d/
```

Comment: @sreeraj also, look into "renice" for commands that are already in progress.

Comment: `ionice` is likelier to be effective with and I/O bound process like cp.

Answer (score 5):

With `cp` you may be more I/O-limited than CPU-limited.  To adjust the I/O priority, you can use the `ionice` command - see `man ionice`.  For example, to get 'Best effort' priority with highest preference among all best effort processes, run

```
ionice -c 2 -n 0 cp -r dir1 /d/
```

You can also combine it with `nice` to adjust both CPU and I/O priority:

```
ionice -c 2 -n 0 nice -n -20 cp -r dir1 /d/
```

Comment: If you renice the process it implicitly renices IO too.

"The priority within the best effort class will  be dynamically  derived  from  the  cpu  nice level of the process: io_priority = (cpu_nice + 20) / 5."